# Android Support Libraries for custom fonts only work with some components

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to set up custom fonts in an Android app with Support Libraries (for Android >6) and for some reason only `TextView`s seem to work with them.

This is the code for the layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/ItemPrefs"
            android:text="this is textview"
            android:fontFamily="@font/questrial" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/swcCustomSwitch"
            style="@style/ItemPrefs"
            android:text="this is switch"
            android:fontFamily="@font/questrial" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the code for the font file:

```
<font-family
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/questrial_regular" />

</font-family>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: TextView with custom font, Switch with standard font]
*`TextView` with custom font, `Switch` with standard font.*

But then, if I set it up programatically...

```
{
    Typeface customFont = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), R.font.questrial);

    swcCustomSwitch.setTypeface(customFont);
}
```

...then everything works...

[image: Both TextView and Switch with custom font]
*Both `TextView` and `Switch` with custom font.*

Am I missing any "compat" thing or something? I would not like to specify the font for every component in every layout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to create your own Switch component, just extends from the parent. Inside initialize method add a few lines of code which will get fontFamily from xml param and apply to the text title. I think you could look inside TextView code will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I already said that with `.setTypeface()` the `Switch` works (with `.setSwitchTypeface()` I would have to change every `Switch` with `SwitchCompat`), but that "I would not like to specify the font for every component".

Comment: I did, faced the same problem: [Reported issue on GitHub](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/310). I would rather **not** use a 3rd party library.

Comment: Ok, all you need to create your own `Switch` component, just extends from the parent. Inside initialize method add a few lines of code which will get fontFamily from xml param and apply to the text title. I think you could look inside `TextView` code will be the same. Got it?

Comment: Good idea, it actually works as temporary workaround. Could you edit it as answer so I could mark it as answer to the post?

Comment: @DavidTaberneroM. Yeah